# Make work find pipe awk command in Makefile

Tags: awk, makefile, find

I have this find awk line to get python code analyse::

```
$ find ./ -name '*.py' -exec  wc -l {} \; | sort -n| awk '{print $0}{s+=$0}END{print s}'
12 ./gb/__init__.py
23 ./gb/value_type.py
40 ./setup.py
120 ./gb/libcsv.py
200
$
```

I try to put it in a Makefile::

```
$ cat Makefile
python_count_lines: clean
    @find ./ -name '*.py' -exec  wc -l {} \; | sort -n| awk '{print \$0}{s+=\$0}END{print s}'
```

But this did not work::

```
$ make python_count_lines
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near }
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'python_count_lines' failed
make: *** [python_count_lines] Error 2
$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bertrand Martel is correct that you need to escape dollar signs from make by doubling them, not prefixing them with backslashes (see [info here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html)).

However, the rest of that suggestion is not right and won't work; first, you should almost never use the `shell` function in a recipe.  Second, using the `info` function here cannot work because in the first line you've set a *shell* variable `RES` equal to some value, then you try to print the *make* variable `RES` in the second line; not only that but each line is run in a separate shell, and also all make variable and function references are expanded up-front, before any part of the recipe is passed to the shell.

You just need to do this:

```
python_count_lines: clean
        @find ./ -name '*.py' -exec  wc -l {} \; | sort -n| awk '{print $$0}{s+=$$0}END{print s}'
```

Comment: You are right, I had some tab issue that made me think it was working